# Insert to datagridview when SELECT query has WHERE condition

Tags: c#, datagridview, insert

Hi I use this code to Load and Insert data to a table using datagridview in C# windows application.

```
        SqlCommand sCommand;
        SqlDataAdapter sAdapter;
        SqlCommandBuilder sBuilder;
        DataSet sDs;
        DataTable sTable;          
private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {    
                string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
                string sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
                sCommand = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                sAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sCommand);
                sBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter);
                sDs = new DataSet();
                sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "mytable");
                sTable = sDs.Tables["mytable"];
                connection.Close();
                dataGridView1.DataSource = sDs.Tables["mytable"];
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                save_btn.Enabled = false;
                dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            }

            private void new_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false;
                save_btn.Enabled = true;
                new_btn.Enabled = false;
                delete_btn.Enabled = false;
            }

            private void delete_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index);
                    sAdapter.Update(sTable);
                }
            }

            private void save_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                sAdapter.Update(sTable);
                dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
                save_btn.Enabled = false;
                new_btn.Enabled = true;
                delete_btn.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

It's ok and work, But When I try to work with a query that have condition then No row add to datagrid and mytable anymore

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable where col2 = 1";
```

Comment: your query is not working then, did you check it by running in your SQL server

Comment: yes my query is worked, and load data to datagridview but I can INSERT new row

Comment: means the query with the WHERE clause is working, but it is not loading into datagridview ?

Comment: How it's possible, When I only change sql query and new query is correct